# SoapUI web service authentication programmatically

Tags: web-services, junit, soapui

I am writing SOAP web service tests using SoapUi API. I am using SoapUITestCaseRunner for that.

My code looks like

```
public class MyRunner extends SoapUITestCaseRunner{
  public void runTest(){
     setProjectFile("pro_file_path");
     setEndpoint("endpoint");
     setUsername("username");
     setPassword("password");
     setTestSuite("testSuiteName");
     setTestCase("TestCaseName");
     run();
 }

}
public class MyTestClass(){
    @Test
    public void test(){
        new MyRunner().runTest();
    }
}
```

> But username and password are getting passed as properties (I could see them in junit failure logs).
>   
>  And service is saying me 401-unauthorized ? Am I missing anything? Is there anything need to be done to pass username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The problem is with the version of SoapUI I am using to create project.xml file. If we create project using version below 5.0.0 and use 5.0.0 while writing junit it won't work.

Actually, the it seems that SoapUI ahs made changes to authentication part in 5.0.0 which has few more options like NTML. 
So we have to configure authentication type in project.xml and send the username and password either pre-configured in project.xml or manually through junit.